# How to get data from an Activity in this case?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
Activity_A:

{
   //calling Activity B where i find the user current location lat and lng
   Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}

Activity_B
{
   //after getting user lat and lng, use them in Activity_C to show the initial marker position
   Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_B.this, Activity_C.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   //i don't this Activity_B to show up on back press in Activity_C hence finish(), anyways this Activity_B has no layout
   finish();
}

Activity_C:

{
   //Show a map with marker at position using lat, lng values from Activity_B, allow user to drag the marker and get the new lat, lng. and then finish this Activity to go to Activity_A
   finish();
}
```

I want this Activity_C send back values of new lat, lng to ACtivity_A without any shared preferences or global variables, i mean by using `startActivityForResult` and `onACtivityResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setResult` and inside activity `A` get the all data inside `OnActivityResult`. But starting activity from A to B you need to use `startActivityForResult` with result code. Else you can use `broadcast receivers` independent of all the activities you can send and receive in any activity class.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try chaining the activities like this::


Activity_A:

{
   //calling Activity B where i find the user current location lat and lng
   Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
*****startActivityForResult******

   startActivity(intent);
}

Activity_B
{
   //after getting user lat and lng, use them in Activity_C to show the initial marker position
   Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_B.this, Activity_C.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   //i don't this Activity_B to show up on back press in Activity_C hence finish(), anyways this Activity_B has no layout
*****startActivityForResult******
   finish();
}

Activity_C:

{
   //Show a map with marker at position using lat, lng values from Activity_B, allow user to drag the marker and get the new lat, lng. and then finish this Activity to go to Activity_A
   finish();
}
```